# Swift : Core Data Integer weird values

Tags: swift, core-data, nsnumber

Just started learning Swift and have a question around Core Data. I have a very simple entity named "Score" with one attribute "points" which is of type Int16.

Here's my data model class:

```
class Score: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var points: Int}
```

Here's the code on my View Controller:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Score", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
        let score = Score(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

        println(score.points)
}
```

What prints in the console is this number: -5764607523034234879

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I looked elsewhere and perhaps I need to do something with NSNumber, but I'm unfamiliar with that class.

Shouldn't score.points be empty right now?

Comment: Where do you assign the point ? The one that you are seeing is some garbage value. Make sure to have some default value for the attribute, you can edit that in your DataModel editor in Xcode.

Comment: I don't assign it anywhere. Does it not start as nil? When I go to assign a value in the data model class "@NSManaged var points : Int = 0" I get an error saying NSManaged variables cannot have initial values

Comment: Have you marked it to be nil. Is it optional ? How can it be nil then ?

Comment: Sorry, edited my comment. I'm not sure what's the best practice in doing this? I'm creating a small little "cookie-clicker" type game. This assumes the user starts at 0 points.

Comment: Look at the code your points is not optional which also means that it cannot be nil. So, if you dont assign some default value to the attribute through the model editor, it can be garbage.

Comment: Hi Generator - thanks for answering. I guess my question now is, how can the code just randomly assign a garbage value to score.points? Shouldn't it just fail to run then?

Comment: Ok, thats how the system works. You should either make it optional, which would give you nil if your value does not exist or else you can make some default value. There is nothing as such that system will initialize it with 0 value. It just assigns some sufficiently larger number which is nan or just a garbage.

Comment: For a Core Data "Int 16" property the corresponding class property should be an `NSNumber` or an `Int16`, but not `Int`. (Did you write that class yourself or is it auto-generated from Xcode?)

Comment: Hi Martin, I wrote it myself (just trying to learn basics). I realized it should be of type NSNumber, and have gotten plenty of feedback to just used to auto-generated stuff. A good learning opportunity nonetheless - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got your questions answered, but you CAN set a default value for attributes in `NSManagedObject`.  Just not via code.

[image]

The default value is set when you save without setting a value, so you still need to deal with the uninitialized pointer reference to a `NSNumber` value until it is saved.